# How do I disable rounding for the bottom edges in a bar chart? ver-9.0.1

Tags: highcharts

I use highcarts and set the rounding for the bar chart, but I do not want the bottom edges rounded, how can I turn them off? Where:end unfortunately doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `highcharts-border-radius` plugin.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bL2c4hnj/

API Reference:
https://github.com/highcharts/rounded-corners

Comment: Great! And from which version can I do it through the public API?

Comment: Customizable border radius is available straight from the API since the last version - Highcharts 11 - Check demos: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.borderRadius

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution, how can I connect it to the library if it's downloaded and in cdn?

Comment: This feature is available out of the box in the core, so it is not necessary to load additional modules. In that case, only the core script is enough - `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find this module in my version 9.0.1, but I was able to connect it by adding it to cdn, thank you for your help.